# What's the different between the "friend" and "friendship" tag?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Are there any differences between those two tags? Why do we have both?

The [friends](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friends) tag have a description;

> For questions about interactions with friends, people with whom you share personal details of your lives and enjoy shared activities.

But, the [friendship](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friendship) one doesn't.

So, should the [friendship](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friendship) tag be turned into a synonym of [friends](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friends)?

Comment: Note that there's a pending synonym request for the two since July: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest

Comment: @scohe001 who can deal with those pending flags?

Comment: @Noon: For example... you :P https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms

Comment: @dhein Wow, that was really well hidden, thanks for the link!